# What is this notification icon for

Tags: notification-icons

[image]

Can anyone help me figure out what this icon is for???

Comment: What is shown when you pull down the notification panel?

Comment: The logo is of google play news stand.

Answer (score 3):

I believe that icon indicates a new notification from [Google Play Newsstand](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.apps.magazines&hl=en).

**Edit:**

Confirmed my assumption this morning when a notification popped up:
[image: Screenshot of Google Play Newsstand notification]

I don't know how to take a screenshot of the status icon bar, so you'll have to take my word that the icon appeared there too.

Answer (score 0):

To check which app is giving you that notification, pull down the notification tray and you will see a notification item with that icon. Make a long click on that notification icon and it will show you the name of the app and other options for notification control.